# rsync copy new files only, no updates?

Tags: linux, rsync

I would like to use rsync to copy files from a remote server. I would like to

- only copy files from server, not push any back out.
- copy files that don't exist. If the remote file is newer I **do not** want to copy it
- have it automatic. This prompts me for my password everytime and i would like it to be ran by cron. So how do I run it in a bash script executed by cron?

Comment: To "have it automatic" the `--password-file` option would provide the password to the server prompt. The file should just contain the passphrase in plaintext and do not allow other users to have read access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Points 1 and 2: How to specify what to copy is best answered by reading the rsync [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). In your case, look especially at --ignore-existing flag.

Point 3: This [tutorial](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) should get you going using passwordless ssh with rsync.  Summary: set up passwordless ssh and use '-e ssh' to tell rsync to use ssh instead of rsh to connect to the remote host.

Comment: I looked at the man and i cant figure out what will allow me to copy new files only and not update.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, since pjz answered the rest, I believe you can use the --ignore-existing switch to only get new files.

From http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html:

> This tells rsync to skip updating
>   files that already exist on the
>   destination (this does not ignore
>   existing directories, or nothing would
>   get done). See also --existing. This
>   option is a transfer rule, not an
>   exclude, so it doesn't affect the data
>   that goes into the file-lists, and
>   thus it doesn't affect deletions. It
>   just limits the files that the
>   receiver requests to be transferred.
>
> This option can be useful for those
>   doing backups using the --link-dest
>   option when they need to continue a
>   backup run that got interrupted. Since
>   a --link-dest run is copied into a new
>   directory hierarchy (when it is used
>   properly), using --ignore existing
>   will ensure that the already-handled
>   files don't get tweaked (which avoids
>   a change in permissions on the
>   hard-linked files). This does mean
>   that this option is only looking at
>   the existing files in the destination
>   hierarchy itself.